SQL Server WEB edition "application" limitation
I'm struggling to get the "application" limitation of the SQL Server WEB edition...
Some said (like AWS) you can use that edition ONLY with .. WEB application !
It appears to me that the description on the Microsoft license page is just an advice of possible use, not an obligation : "SQL Server Web edition is a low total-cost-of-ownership option for Web hosters....."
Does someone have reliable information on that ? Is it possible to use SQL Server WEB edition in a little classic client/server Windows based application ?

Is your question regarding the licensing implications (if you're gonna be in compliance with Microsoft terms while using the software) or functional implications (if you're gonna be able to access the database and query the data)?

I'm asking for licensing implications -> if Is it "allowed" (by Microsoft) to use SQL Server WEB edition in a little classic client/server Windows based application, or if it HAS to be used in a WEB application.

In that case I recommend you check this thread before you rely on any advice regarding software licensing that was not provided from an oficial vendor.

I'm asking as it could be obvious (for other) even if I don't get it...
For me, allowing to use the SQL WEB edition only for "WEB server", is as stupid as having for example a "Letters Word edition" : only to edit letters (no company internal documents !!!!)
But I could be wrong... not sure... this is why I ask.

Indeed, you could be wrong =/ unfortunately, there's no such thing as "stupid" or "obvious" when it comes to software licensing. Microsoft sells a license to the software and another to have the right to access the software you have licensed (CAL) - not obvious at all!
